# Proof that block of independent Gaussian symbols has higher mutual information than correlated Gaussian symbols in band- & power-limited AWGN channel

Tags: information-theory

Given a discrete-time AWGN channel defined by:
$$
Y = X + N
$$
where $N$ is a zero-mean Gaussian RV with $E[N^2] = P_N$ representing additive noise,  $X$ is the transmitted symbol with power constraint $E[X^2] \leq P_S$, and $X$ and $N$ are independent.

The mutual information between $X$ and $Y$, denoted $I(X; Y)$, is given by:
$$
I(X; Y) = E \left[ \log_2 \left( \frac{p(X,Y)}{p(X) p(Y)} \right) \right] = E \left[ \log_2 \left( \frac{p(Y|X)}{ p(Y)} \right) \right] = H(Y) - H(Y|X)
$$
where $H(Y)$ is the differential entropy of $Y$ and $H(Y|X)$ is the [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Motivation). It is pretty straightforward to show that the input symbol distribution that maximizes the mutual information is when $X \sim \mathcal N(0, P_S)$, leading to the channel capacity $C_s$ (per channel use):
$$
C_s = \frac{1}{2} \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{P_S}{P_N} \right)
$$
In other words, for a block of symbols with block length $L=1$, Gaussian symbols maximize mutual information.

In a bandlimited AWGN channel with bandwidth $B$, using sinc pulses you can transmit and detect a maximum of $2B$ independent symbols per second, which yields the well-known channel capacity $C$ (expressed in bits/second) of:
$$
C = B \log_2 \left( 1 + \frac{P_S}{P_N} \right)
$$

In many textbooks, this formula is listed as "the" channel capacity of a band- and power- limited AWGN channel. However, this statement seems to assume the upper bound is reached when the transmitted symbols are independent.

To illustrate this, consider a coding scheme over a block of symbols $\mathbf X = [X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_L]$. If each $X_i$ is independent, then $p(\mathbf X) = p(X_1) p(X_2) \ldots p(X_L)$ in which case each channel output also becomes independent so $p(\mathbf Y) = p(Y_1) p(Y_2) \ldots p(Y_L)$. The mutual information for a block of symbols, defined by:
$$
I(\mathbf X; \mathbf Y) =  H(\mathbf Y) - H(\mathbf Y| \mathbf X)
$$
will then factor into:
$$
I(\mathbf X; \mathbf Y) =  H( Y_1) - H( Y_1|  X_1) + H( Y_2) - H( Y_2|  X_2) + \ldots + H( Y_L) - H( Y_L|  X_L) \\
= I(X_1; Y_1) + I(X_2; Y_2) + \ldots + I(X_L; Y_L)
$$
which then leads to the $B \log_2 ( 1 + P_S/P_N)$ formula above with $2B$ independent channel uses per second.

My question is-- is there some proof that i.i.d. zero-mean Gaussian symbols with power $P_N$ always will have the highest mutual information over a block of length $L>1$? (In other words, no other joint coding scheme $p(\mathbf X)$ will perform better.)

Comment: I don't know the answer but am interested and was curious if a uniformly distributed RV would out-perform since it is spreading that information content uniformly along the possible magnitudes versus given a higher density close in as a Gaussian would? Have you tried for comparison?

Comment: @DanBoschen That is a good question. For a single RV, the uniform distribution does maximize entropy when you impose an amplitude constraint (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution), whereas Gaussian maximizes entropy when you impose an average power constraint (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).  I think the intuition is that with no amplitude constraint but with a power constraint, the PAPR is allowed to increase to infinity.

Comment: That makes good sense- thanks!

Comment: This comes from the chain rule and the fact that conditioning cannot increase entropy. For example, see [this proof of the converse part of the noisy coding theorem](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee376a/files/2017-18/lecture_11.pdf).